# How can I change the address for my ROD (Return of Documents) application?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I applied for a NTL BRP application a couple of months ago. 
Last Thursday, I applied to have the application cancelled and the documents returned. They said it would take 10 working days to return so I put in my current home address. However, I am due to move address soon, is there a way for me to change the address to which my documents are sent?

Comment: NTL's are handled over in Expats, please use that site. http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: What's NTL? What's BRP? Can your country's postal service not forward mail from your old address to your new one?